# How do I avoid getting a fatal error while installing a plugin for wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I get the following error while installing plugin in Wordpress.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exeded in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1513.

I fixed the following in xampp's `php.ini`.

```
max_execution_time = 600

max_input_time = 600

memory_limit = 512M

post_max_size = 21M
```

But the error still persists. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php and http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: You need to restart Apache services.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to restart the web server for the updated php.ini settings to take effect. You can use the output of [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to check if max_execution_time has changed to the new value and also to check the location of the loaded .ini files.

Comment: You are absolutely right.The max_execution_time=30 in phpinfo().It has not been changed.I restarted my xampp server . But the error still persists.How to get rid of it?

Comment: Perhaps the .ini file that you are editing is not being loaded. Did you check the location of loaded .ini files in the phpinfo() output?